# Alternative to Cypress EZ-USB FX CY3671

Tags: java, usb, jsr

This is a pretty special question and I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the right platform to ask it but I try anyway...

I'm currently writing an implementation of [JSR-80](http://javax-usb.org/) (javax.usb) and just found out that there is a Test Compliance Kit available. But this test compliance kit requires special hardware: A "Cypress EZ-USB FX Integrated Circuit Xcelerator Development Kit CY3671". The TCK contains a firmware image for this controller.

The problem is: I can't find this developer board anywhere. I only find obscure shops which sell it for 800 USD. As a Open Source developer I can't afford this. Now the question is: Is there some compatible alternative? A successor from Cypress maybe which is compatible to the firmware and which is more likely to be found on ebay? I found a "EZ-USB FX2 Board" on ebay which is affordable (50 USD) but I have no idea if it is compatible.

Comment: You'll probably be fine if you can find any developer board with the same EZ-USB controller on it (CY7C64613). I don't think the FX2 is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The FX microcontroller was the product that support USB 1.1 standard. Now the last version of the chip in FX2LP.
The evolution is: FX, FX2, FX2LP (rohs compliant chip).
FX2/LP is not completely compatible with an FX, but it extends its capabilities with USB 2.0 and probably increase the data amd program memory.
If you have a copy of a FX2LP firmware, the procedure to download the fw on board should be exactly the same (look for "soft configuration" and "re-enumeration").

Refere to this [link](http://www.cypress.com/?id=193&rtID=110) for the development boards.

I hope this info could help you.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest contacting the JSR spec lead, Boyd Dimmock. 
The [JSR80](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=80) spec contains her contact information